# .NET - Which Control has Focus? - Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, focus

I am currently translating a windows form application, written in VB6, to a webpage written in Visual Studio 2010.

In VB6 it is easy to find out which control has focus on the form using '.getFocus()'. I have come to the conclusion it is not that easy, if at all possible, in vb2008.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: The UI model for a web page is *very* different from a winform app.  Yes, there is no Focused property.  That happens in the browser, a thousand miles away from your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms you can create a *foreach* loop like this and check if a specific control has focus:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
 if (item.Focused)
  //codes to handle the condition
}
```

Or like spacemonkeyes said, use `this.ActiveControl` or VB's version `Me.ActiveControl`

However for a webpage I think you have to use JavaScript. The *document* object has a property named **ActiveElement** which as far as I know, only IE supports this property:
`document.ActiveElement`
It returns a reference to the focused control.
To use it on the server side, you have to have a form which is submitted to the server or you could use Ajax to submit that particular control. Pretty complex codings are required.

Answer (score 1):

`Me.ActiveControl` will give you a control object reference. This returns windows form control, but you should be able to use `Me.ActiveControl.Name` or one of the other parameters to get what you require, returns nothing if no control has focus

But as pointed out, this only works in a windows form, web applications you will need to do some javascript skullduggery to get what you want.